# C++: WMI query Win32_Process return incorrect value

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I want to query processes' info using WMI, but it occurs that some values are not correct.

In the following code, I don't know why **WorkingSetSize** and **UserModeTime** always return wrong values.

The query:

```
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);
```

Get properties:

```
        ProcessInfo x;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.imageName = vtProp.bstrVal;

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessId", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.pid = vtProp.ulVal;

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ParentProcessId", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.ppid = vtProp.ulVal;

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SessionId", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.sessionID = vtProp.ulVal;

        x.sessionName = L"N/A";

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"WorkingSetSize", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.memUsage = vtProp.ulVal;
        
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"UserModeTime", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        x.cpuTime = vtProp.ullVal;
        // Get Owner
        x.userName = L"N/A";

        ret.push_back(x);

        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
```

And the result:

```
Process Name                  PID     PPID Session Name       Session ID    Mem Usage Status                User Name            CPU Time (ms) Windows Title

System Idle Process             0        0 N/A                         0 3100857080 K                       N/A                  1897181277720
System                          4        0 N/A                         0 3100857176 K                       N/A                  1897181277720
Registry                      108        4 N/A                         0 3100857896 K                       N/A                  1897181277720
smss.exe                      380        4 N/A                         0 3100857272 K                       N/A                  1897181277720
csrss.exe                     528      480 N/A                         0 3100856168 K                       N/A                  1897181434328
wininit.exe                   640      480 N/A                         0 3100856216 K                       N/A                  1897181277720
```

Comment: You never check the HRESULT return nor the VT type of vtProp. You are leaking a bstr. Your code does not produce the output you have shown.

Comment: @Anders the HRESULT is always 0, which means success. Here is the complete code: https://github.com/lebaoworks/C_Utilities/blob/main/wait/processquery.cpp

Comment: Again, you are not checking the return of `pclsObj->Get` nor the VT type!

Comment: @Anders check the code please, all `pclsObj->Get` in my code return 0 (success), and if getting `PageFileUsage` (uint32) wrong, so getting `ProcessId` (uint32) must be wrong too.